# Processing input csv using JS on client

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo, odoo-16

I have a form view where the user can upload a csv file.

`source_file = fields.Binary(string='CSV Input', attachment=True)`

`<field name="source_file"/>`

I want to have a button 'Validate CSV' that will run a js function to validate the csv for any non-printable characters and show any rows that contain invalid characters in the view

I am new to odoo development so I am not able to bind the js function to the button and access the file in the js function

I can figure out the validation logic but I need help with the js file syntax such that it will be bound to the button and show the result in the view

Thanks a lot

I tried writing the js function in static/src/js folder, the file loads when the page loads but the button is disabled by default. Looks like it cant find the function or something. I am also doubtful about how the js will fetch the file from the DOM or field

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.